# Qt vulkan classes not found

Tags: c++, qt, class, vulkan

Using Qt 5.10 and qmake 3.1, my compiler gives this output:

```
expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

My code:

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>
#include <QVulkanWindow>

class VulkanRenderer : public QVulkanWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    VulkanRenderer();

    ~VulkanRenderer();
private:
};
```

I also added the line `CONFIG += vulkan` to my .pro file.

Comment: `CONFIG += vulkan` should not be necessary.

Comment: Do the vulkan examples in `Qt\Examples\Qt-5.10.0\vulkan` work for you?

Comment: They actually dont't, I'm getting the same errors

Comment: Works for me on Windows with rc2... Do you use the non-UWP bundles if on Windows? Is the contents of  `VULKAN_SDK` environment variable set correctly?

Comment: It should find the headers, I installed them via apt

Comment: Should. Apparently Qt does not like something about your env. What is your `VK_HEADER_VERSION`? I assume `QT_CONFIG(vulkan) == 0, because that seem to be the only guard?

Comment: Any change using the new (release) version?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qvulkaninstance.html#details):

> Vulkan support may get automatically disabled for a given Qt build due to not having the necessary Vulkan headers available at build time. When this is the case, and the output of configure indicates Vulkan support is disabled, the QVulkan* classes will be unavailable.

Make sure it's not that case.

[This blog](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/06/16/vulkan-support-qt-5-10-part-2/) seems to go into some detail how to troubleshoot this.

Check if you have Vulkan SDK installed and `VULKAN_SDK` environment variable set.

Comment: I built qt using the installer from the official website, and when building it from source, the configure script find the vulkan headers